# Swift: Dismissing all view controllers and then presenting a view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I'm looking for a way to dismiss all presented view controllers, and THEN present a view controller.

In my app, there's a main page, and the user can then click on a button that takes them to another page, and then they can click a button to submit some information. After they click to submit the evidence, I want to close all of the view controllers (so they get to the main page), and then I want to present a "Congratulations" screen. Ideally, this would be what I want to do:

```
self.view.window?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
        let congratsPopup = K.mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "congratsController") as! CongratsController
        self.view.window?.rootViewController!.present(congratsPopup, animated:true, completion:nil)
    })
```

Any ideas?

Cheers,
Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dismiss all viewcontrollers with below code block. In the completion block you can get the topViewController and you can present new viewController over topViewController. I also wrote down an extension for get the topViewController on the window.

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: { [weak self] in
            // Get Top Controller With Extension
            let topController = UIApplication.topViewController()
            // Pressent New Controller over top controller
            let congratsPopup = K.mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "congratsController") as! CongratsController
            topController?.present(congratsPopup, animated: true, completion: nil)
        })
```

Get Top View Controller Extension

```
extension UIApplication {
class func topViewController(controller: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    if let navigationController = controller as? UINavigationController {
        return topViewController(controller: navigationController.visibleViewController)
    }
    if let tabController = controller as? UITabBarController {
        if let selected = tabController.selectedViewController {
            return topViewController(controller: selected)
        }
    }
    if let presented = controller?.presentedViewController {
        return topViewController(controller: presented)
    }
    return controller
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alihan - this works perfectly! Much appreciated :)

Comment: Just implementing this, and i'm getting an error when I go back to the first ViewController. I'm trying to reload a TableView inside the ViewController, but it gives me an "unexpected nil when unwrapping tableview". Any ideas? Thanks again!